# How to make Python strings version agnostic

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, unicode

How do you make Python strings agnostic to the version of Python they're using?

I'm trying to maintain code that works with Python 2.7 and Python 3.*, and I'm running into a lot of counter intuitive errors. For example, this works perfectly in Python 2.7:

```
print('Job: %s' % job)
```

but it fails in Python 3.3 with the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If I change that line to:

```
print(('Job: %s' % job).encode('utf-8'))
```

that fixes it in Python 3.3...but that breaks Python 2.7, which now throws the exact same error.

Trying to manage strings in Python feels like playing whack-a-mole. How do you reliably encode strings so they work in all versions of Python?

Comment: This title is a bit misleading, might need some tweaking.

Comment: `'Job: %s' % job` will fail in both Python 2 and Python 3 in some cases. In Python 2 it will just do the wrong thing silently.

Comment: Show what is in `job`.  It matters.

Answer (score 5):

This should work in both Python 2.7 and [3.3+](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/):

```
print(u'Job: {}'.format(job))
```

If it still fails, then your problem exists elsewhere.  Somehow `job` has already been encoded and you need to define the `__str__` and `__unicode__` magics correctly.

Comment: It _might_ not work in some of the very early python3 versions ... e.g. 3.0, 3.1, ... I'm pretty sure that it works in `3.3` at least, and I don't think anyone is actually using those really early python3 versions anyway.  The relevant PEP is [0414](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/)

Comment: @mgilson Oh, yeah it would be syntax error in 3.2 because of the u prefix.  Thanks, updated.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. But yes, I've implemented both `Job.__unicode__` and `Job.__str__` which returns `self.__unicode__()` for Py3 and `self.__unicode__().encode('utf8')` for Py2.

Comment: Your py2 version is incorrect.  Don't encode the text to bytes.

Comment: Both `__str__` and `__unicode__` should return a text object (this means whatever it returns has the type 'unicode' in python2 and type 'str' in python3).  **We can't help you any more than that, because you haven't posted any code for the `Job` class.**

Comment: @wim, Sorry, all my code's open source and online [here](https://github.com/chrisspen/django-chroniker/blob/master/chroniker/models.py#L660).

Comment: It will be best if you include the code in your question next time.  Regardless, the problem is still [here](https://github.com/chrisspen/django-chroniker/blob/f3721f100d800c5beb03c48ef9b66d963b050aec/chroniker/models.py#L674) as I already mentioned; you're returning bytes from the method when you should be returning text.  Just put `__str__ = __unicode__` you don't need that `__str__` method customized at all.

Comment: @wim, And like I said, that's what I tried, and it breaks Py2.7. Try it yourself. I have extensive unittests.

Comment: A method that I know for a fact works for cross-compat libraries is already described.  I've nothing more to add unless you can edit your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The `six` library is built for things like this:

```
import six
print("%s" % six.u(job))
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution will depend on which precise Python versions you want to target, but if 2.7 is enough for backwards compatibility, you can put

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

which is a no-op in Python 3 (at least 3.2+) and does what you expect in Python 2.7.

```
bash$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Dec 26 2015, 17:47:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> type('hello')
<type 'unicode'>
>>> repr('Götterdämmerung')
"u'G\\xf6tterd\\xe4mmerung'"
```

See the caveats at http://python-future.org/unicode_literals.html which notes that "future" doesn't really cover 3.0-3.2.  As such, this particular thing seems to work like I expect in 3.1, too.